# GCP: Billing Account change on project hosting export dataset. What happens to data in transit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have billing export enabled.

afaik it can take a few days until billing data is ingested into BigQuery and the GCP project hosting the BigQuery dataset for the export has to be linked to the source billing account.

If I change the billing account of the project hosting the BigQuery export target dataset, what will happen to the data that hasn't been ingested yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing! Google need a project with an active billing account to sink the data in it (in fact because you have to pay for the stored data). It's not mandatory to have this project using the same billing account as this one you sink the data.

So, change the billing account of the project, the billing export of the initial billing account will continue, as usual.